# How Redundant Ethernet Bonding Works

Tags: switch

I am currently trying to implement redundancy whereby hosts have 2 eth ports and both ports connect to different switches. If either switch fails (or if any port fails) there will still be a way to reach the other host. The diagram below is adapted from [bonding.txt section 11.2 in the linux drivers documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt)

```
                |                                     |
                |port3                           port3|
          +-----+----+                          +-----+----+
          |          |port2       ISL      port2|          |
          | switch A +--------------------------+ switch B |
          |          |                          |          |
          +-----+----+                          +-----++---+
                |port1                           port1|
                |             +-------+               |
                +--------eth0-+ host1 +-eth1----------+
                |             +-------+               |
                |                                     |
                |             +-------+               |
                +--------eth0-+ host2 +-eth1----------+
                |             +-------+               |
```

**Generalizable Questions**

- Does `eth0` and `eth1` of `host1` have the same IP & MAC address?
- Are packets from `host1` to `host2` duplicated?

  - If yes how would `host2` know to ignore the duplicate packet?
- If link availability checks are done instead of duplicate packets how would `host1` know to stop using `eth0` and start using `eth1`?
- What type of switch configuration would be needed?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: This is definitely more of a network engineering question than a server fault question because it's about how the network (i.e. switches and devices) transmit and handle the data. Redundancy IS a component of networks. Please reopen.

Comment: There are a lot of options.  It does depend somewhat on your switches, too.  If you have switches which support a stacking feature with cross-stack LACP, that will be the easiest way to configure the switches & servers.  In the absence of stacking (or similar MLAG features) things get more complex and are more likely to require a routing protocol or application-awareness.

Comment: If you really feel that this is something for NE, then you need to provide some information about the network devices, such as the models and configurations. The only thing you referred to was the documentation on the Linux drivers, and that is off-topic here. How you configure the hosts is off-topic here. We may be able to help with the configuration of the network devices, but we cannot simply guess what models and configurations. You can refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance, then edit your question.

Comment: Also, your questions about the hosts: "_Does eth0 and eth1 of host1 have the same IP & MAC address?_" and "_If yes how would host2 know to ignore the duplicate packet?_" and "_If link availability checks are done instead of duplicate packets how would host1 know to stop using eth0 and start using eth1?_" are off-topic here, so you should remove those when you edit the question.

Comment: Did you read the linked document? The kernel bonding doc describes what each mode does. (not so much the effect each mode has on the network, but that's a different question)